# How to use PackageImports extension to "shadow" a module?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to "shadow" the Scotty module using the `PackageImports` extension.

**Use case:** For someone using a library `X` make `instrumentedX` available. So, simply by changing `X` to `instrumentedX` in their cabal file, they can use the instrumented version of the library -- without any other change in code.

Here's the module that I want to export, which has the same name, i.e. `Web.Scotty.Trans` as the original module exported by Scotty.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

module Web.Scotty.Trans
  (
    module OS
  , get
  , post
  , put
  , delete
  , patch
  , options
  , addroute
  )
where

import qualified "scotty" Web.Scotty.Trans as OS hiding (get, post, put, delete, patch, options, addroute)
import qualified "scotty" Web.Scotty.Trans as S

import InstrumentedCore
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class(lift)

instrumentedAction original action = original action_
  where
    action_ = do
      st <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
      result <- action
      en <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
      logInstrumentationData InstrumentationData{instrStart=st, instrEnd=en, instrPayload=Render}
      return result


get route action = instrumentedAction (S.get route) action
post route action = instrumentedAction (S.post route) action
put route action = instrumentedAction (S.put route) action
delete route action = instrumentedAction (S.delete route) action
patch route action = instrumentedAction (S.patch route) action
options route action = instrumentedAction (S.options route) action
addroute method route action = instrumentedAction (S.addroute method route) action
```

Here's what my cabal file looks like. While my package depends on `scotty` it uses a different package name for itself, i.e. `instrumentedopaleye` (don't get into the semantics -- I'm trying to shadow a lot of other modules as well!)

```
name:                instrumentedopaleye
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Initial project template from stack
description:         Please see README.md
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/dashboard#readme
license:             BSD3
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2016 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     InstrumentedOpaleye
                     , Instrumented
                     , InstrumentedOpaleye.Internal.PGTypes
                     , InstrumentedOpaleye.Internal.Column
                     , InstrumentedOpaleye.Internal.RunQuery
                     , InstrumentedOpaleye.Internal.HaskellDB.PrimQuery
                     , InstrumentedLucid
                     , Web.Scotty.Trans
                     , InstrumentedCore
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , opaleye
                     , profunctors
                     , product-profunctors
                     , postgresql-simple
                     , mtl
                     , time
                     , stm
                     , text
                     , uuid
                     , lucid
                     , scotty
                     , transformers
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

**The actual error**

And here's what happens when I try to import my version of `Web.Scotty.Trans` in the GHCi. Given that I have explicitly imported **only** my version of `Web.Scotty.Trans` why is GHCi getting confused in resolving the `get` function? Even `:browse Web.Scotty.Trans` is getting confused.

```
Saurabhs-MacBook-Pro:instrumentedopaleye saurabhnanda$ stack exec ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -fobject-code
Prelude> :set -XPackageImports
Prelude> import "instrumentedopaleye" Web.Scotty.Trans
Prelude Web.Scotty.Trans> :i get

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Ambiguous interface for ‘Web.Scotty.Trans’:
      it was found in multiple packages:
      scotty-0.11.0 instrumentedopaleye-0.1.0.0
Prelude Web.Scotty.Trans> :browse Web.Scotty.Trans

<no location info>: error:
    Ambiguous module name ‘Web.Scotty.Trans’:
      it was found in multiple packages:
      scotty-0.11.0@scotty-0.11.0-2sNTuGP3mb3FV66hlreoEd instrumentedopaleye-0.1.0.0@instrumentedopaleye-0.1.0.0-EAOrgrhUGi83yaJJ8gDGX4
```

Comment: Is it relevant that you misspelled `"instrumentedopaleye"` in ghci?

Comment: It's not getting confused, it's providing you helpful suggestions :) As Reid Burton pointed out, you have a typo in the module name in the package import statement.

Comment: @ReidBarton Thanks for pointing that out. Have updated my GHCi session output. GHCi is still getting confused with a different error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing this behavior even *before* you do a package-qualified import. For example, if I have both `cryptonite` and `crypto-api` installed with stack previously, then

```
> stack exec ghci
$ :browse Crypto.Random
```

causes an `ambiguous module name` error. This is a problem I've run into a lot; my solution is to use the `-hide-package` flag:

```
> stack exec ghci
$ :set -hide-package cryptonite
$ :browse Crypto.Random
```

As an added bonus, you no longer need `PackageImports` at all: ghci is completely ignoring `cryptonite`.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to make this work in GHCi without explicitly hiding `scotty` as per [crockeea's answer][1]

Also, due to [Haskell's module limitation][2] one cannot re-export a qualified import. Therefore, here's how I managed to solve my original problem of shadowing scotty:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

module Web.Scotty.Trans
  (
    module Web.Scotty.Trans -- which is the current module
  , module Web.Scotty.TransOriginal -- the original module MINUS the shadowed methods
  )
where

import Web.Scotty.TransOriginal
import qualified "scotty" Web.Scotty.Trans as S

import InstrumentedCore
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class(lift)

instrumentedAction original action = original action_
  where
    action_ = do
      st <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
      result <- action
      en <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
      logInstrumentationData InstrumentationData{instrStart=st, instrEnd=en, instrPayload=Render}
      return result


get route action = instrumentedAction (S.get route) action
post route action = instrumentedAction (S.post route) action
put route action = instrumentedAction (S.put route) action
delete route action = instrumentedAction (S.delete route) action
patch route action = instrumentedAction (S.patch route) action
options route action = instrumentedAction (S.options route) action
addroute method route action = instrumentedAction (S.addroute method route) action
```

The *boilerplate* `Web.Scotty.TransOriginal` which is required only to get around Haskell's limitation around re-exporting qualified imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

module Web.Scotty.TransOriginal
  (
    module Web.Scotty.Trans
  )
where

import "scotty" Web.Scotty.Trans hiding (get, post, put, delete, patch, options, addroute)
```